# How to add space before and after specific character using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have this sentence:
`transportumum min kalo dari kota|tua | mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?`

As you see there are two pipe character in that sentence, I like to add space before and after pipe if it in the middle of word without space. eg: `kota|tua` to `kota | tua`

This is my code so far:

```
def puncNorm(text):
    pat = re.compile(r"\D([|:])\D")
    text = pat.sub(" \\1 ", text)
    return text

text = "transportumum min kalo dari kota|tua | mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?"

text = puncNorm(text)
```

The result add space to every pipe character. So there are double space in `tua  |  mau`:

```
transportumum min kalo dari kota | tua  |  mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?
```

My expected result is:

```
transportumum min kalo dari kota | tua | mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\D` pattern matches any char other than a digit. You may use a word boundary here to make the symbols match only when inside a word:

```
r'\b([|:])\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EscqOV/1)

Note that you also may get rid of the `(...)` as you will need to replace the whole match. A backreference to the whole match is `\g<0>` in Python.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gFslzX):

```
import re
rx = r'\b[|:]\b'
s = "transportumum min kalo dari kota|tua | mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?"
print(re.sub(rx, ' \g<0> ', s))
# => transportumum min kalo dari kota | tua | mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `quantifiers` here like `\s*

`*` means `0` or more of the preceding expression

```
>>> text = "transportumum min kalo dari kota|tua | mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?"
>>> re.sub(r'(\s*\|\s*)',' | ',text)
'transportumum min kalo dari kota | tua | mau ke galeri nasional naik transjakarta jurusan apa ya?'
```

Comment: This `r'(\s*\|\s*)(?is)'` pattern will also [find `|` in `||||||` string](https://regex101.com/r/sblqk4/1). The `(?is)` modifiers make no sense here: there is no `.` nor letters in the pattern.

Comment: should I delete my answer ??

Comment: Well, it would be OK if you explained why you think it is helpful for OP. There is a requirement: *in the middle of word without space*. That is why I added a note.

Comment: This pattern will catch things like `a| b` or `a |b`, which is possibly a good thing; though it's not clear from the OP's limited problem description.